# Image flicker on custom image gallery

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, sanity

My component loads 2 images and then animates opacity between them to fade into the next image. This is all mediated by a setInterval that changes the index for the images every second.

The issue is that just after the first image transitions into the second, the first image briefly shows again. This only happens on the first index. I have tried this on both Chrome and Firefox and the issue is consistent across both.

Here is my code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import utils from "../hooks/utils";


const ImageSlider = ({ images, speed = 1000 }) => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

  const styles = {
    slider: {
      position: "relative",
      height: "100vh",
      display: "flex",
    },
    image: {
      width: "100vw",
      objectFit: "cover",
      animationName: "out",
      animationTimingFunction: "ease-in-out",
      animationDuration: `${speed}ms`,
      zIndex: "2",
    },
    image2: {
      width: "100vw",
      objectFit: "cover",
      marginLeft: "-100vw",
      zIndex: "1",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      //please remember this in the future
      setCurrent((current + 1) % images.length);
    }, speed);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  });

  if (!Array.isArray(images) || images.length == 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div style={styles.slider}>
        {utils.urlArray(images, "", 1000).map((image, index, array) => (
          <>
            {index === current && (
              <>
                <img
                  style={styles.image}
                  src={image}
                  key={`${index}_${current}_0`}
                />
                <img
                  style={styles.image2}
                  src={array[(index + 1) % array.length]}
                  key={`${index}_${current}_1`}
                />
              </>
            )}
          </>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ImageSlider;
```

This is the first time I have built a component like this so I can't seem to think what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you use `map` to just display 2 images?

Comment: that is a result of doing no refactoring

Comment: Why not simply do this with CSS? Using JS to crossfade images infinitely seems an overkill as each time the state changes, the component will re-render and possibly flash during repaint.

Comment: How would you implement this solely with CSS? I saw my options as either I load in all images in the array (10+) and cycle through them with CSS or dynamically load them via JS as to not have such a load.